# How to find out the level of involvement of Openssl in Java's io.netty.handler.ssl package?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, netty

I am using the netty library in Java and I am creating an SSL context with OpenSSL as the provider. I wanted to find out exactly which functions from OpenSSL are being called when I run this java code. Is there any way to find this out? I wanted to see if the certificate verification is something that is done using OpenSSL functions or if it is something that happens on the application level code itself.